# Bootstrap 4 - change position of carousel controls

Tags: css, carousel, bootstrap-4

I've got a simple `bootstrap 4` (beta-v2) carousel:

```
<div id="carouselSteam" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        {% for key, value in results.items %}
            {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    {% include "games/result_table.html" with key=key value=value %}
                </div>
            {% else %}
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    {% include "games/result_table.html" with key=key value=value %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselSteam" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselSteam" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

My issue is that the `carousel-inner` can be quite long as it contains a table. Currently, the controls appear mid-way down the carousel; ideally I'd like them much closer to the top (say 20% from the top) - does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the latest Bootstrap v4 Beta, the distance of the carousel controls from the bottom of the carousel is controlled by the `bottom` CSS attribute.

Therefore, it's fairly easy to control the placing of the left and right carousel control icons by setting the `bottom percentage`. Here's an example where I place them about 75% of the way from the center of the carousel.

```
.carousel-control-prev,
.carousel-control-next{
      bottom: 75%;
}
```

Here's a working codepen: https://codepen.io/Washable/pen/xPYJma?editors=1100

Answer (score 6):

### In Bootstrap 4 for v4.0.0

```
.carousel-control-prev,
.carousel-control-next{
    align-items: flex-start;; /* Aligns it at the top */
}

.carousel-control-prev,
.carousel-control-next{
    align-items: flex-end;; /* Aligns it at the bottom */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap 4 you can also use :

```
.carousel-control-prev,
.carousel-control-next{
  align-self: flex-end; /* Aligns it at the bottom */
}
```

or

```
.carousel-control-prev,
.carousel-control-next{
  align-self: flex-start; /* Aligns it at the top */
}
```